# Default Directory in Rogue Wave

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

I am trying to get IlvFileChooser to open in a default directory but can't find any option to do that. Any ideas please?

```
IlvFileChooserOptions* opt = new IlvFileChooserOptions(IlvFileChooserOpen);
opt->addFilter("Comma separated files (*.csv)", "csv");

IlvFileChooser* dlg = new IlvFileChooser(SIDGetDisplay(), 0, 0, opt);

if (dlg->get() > 0) 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rogue-wave documentation, it seems like the second argument to `IlvFileChooser` is the default directory.

The documentation is you want is [here](http://docs.roguewave.com/visualization/views/5.5.1/refcppgadgets/classIlvFileChooser.html).